# Numpy Array to SQL Table

Tags: python, sql, arrays, numpy

I am trying to save a number of pickled Numpy arrays into an SQL database. The Numpy arrays are 3D and of the form `(Name (text), Data (floats), Date (int)`.

I am currently doing it as following (for array `arr` containing the data and `names` and `dates` as references containing actual names and dates respective to `arr`)

```
name_size, ~, date_size = arr.shape
for i in range(name_size):
    for j in range(date_size):
        insert_into_db(name[i], date[j], arr[i,:,j)
```

However this is very slow. I am wondering if there is not a far more efficient way by just considering the object `arr` as a whole.

For example insert the references in `names` and `dates` into the database first  and then somehow just copy the values in `arr` straight in all at once (where they are ordered and flattened correctly in reference to the `Name` and `Date` values we have just inserted.

Comment: Why are you using SQL for pickling numpy arrays ? you can always use `Pickle` module for python to store almost all the Python objects in a `.p` file and access when required ? It would reduce a lot of overhead.

Comment: I'm not using SQL to pickle, I am creating a database of objects I had previously pickled for more efficient querying. The format of the pickled object was a numpy array but this will be irrelevant once the information has been inserted into the database.

Answer (score 2):

If your database cannot hold native numpy arrays, you can use the `dumps` or `tostring` methods.

`dumps` pickles the data to a `bytes` object in Python 3.x and a `str` object in Python 2.x, which can then be stored in the database as a string or raw byte sequence.  The catch is that the pickle format can change between python or numpy versions, so a different version of numpy or python won't necessarily be able to read it (although numpy developers try to keep the pickle reader as backwards-compatible as possible):

```
testarr = np.arange(20)
data = testarr.dumps()
```

Which gives you (in python 3.x, it is different in python 2.x):

```
b'\x80\x02cnumpy.core.multiarray\n_reconstruct\nq\x00cnumpy\nndarray\nq\x01K\x00\x85q\x02c_codecs\nencode\nq\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00bq\x04X\x06\x00\x00\x00latin1q\x05\x86q\x06Rq\x07\x87q\x08Rq\t(K\x01K\x14\x85q\ncnumpy\ndtype\nq\x0bX\x02\x00\x00\x00i8q\x0cK\x00K\x01\x87q\rRq\x0e(K\x03X\x01\x00\x00\x00<q\x0fNNNJ\xff\xff\xff\xffJ\xff\xff\xff\xffK\x00tq\x10b\x89h\x03X\xa0\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00q\x11h\x05\x86q\x12Rq\x13tq\x14b.'
```

`tostring` works similarly in that it converts the array to a string format.  It has the advantage that it should be the same across python and numpy versions, but has the disadvantage that it doesn't store the dimensions, so you would need to keep the dimensions (and whether the array is `C` or `Fortran` order) in the database to properly reconstruct the array (unless it is always the same):

```
testarr = np.arange(20)
data = testarr.tostring()
```

Which gives you (this will be the same in Python 2.x and 3.x, except that in Python 3.x it will be a `bytes` type and in python 2.x it will be a `str` type):

```
b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x05\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0b\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x11\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x12\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x13\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
```

Comment: Hi TheBlackCat, maybe my question wasn't entirely clear. I now no longer care about the fact my object was a numpy array, I just want to get the data in the numpy array into the SQL database. In effect my numpy array is currently acting as a very inefficient database that I have to keep loading into memory and querying.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to dump the array and convert it in hexadecimal:

array_5_str = array_5.dumps().hex() # to save it in the table

To convert it into a ndarray again:

array_5_from_str = pickle.loads(bytes.fromhex(array_5_str))

You can compare the two ndarrays with: comparison = array_5 == array_5_from_str equal_arrays = comparison.all() print(equal_arrays)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).