# Read the print output as a variable python

Tags: python, list

I have a variable that when I print it gives the value

`"[[247 164][249 190][255 215][261 239][270 263][286 283][305 300][324 317][345 320][367 315][388 297][408 277][425 254]..."`

and I am wondering if i could set the print value to a variable like:

```
a = print b
```

Comment: No, `print` returns None. Why would you want to do this? Check [xy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @kabanus because the array being printed is a numpy array which I cant upload to a sql database, so i was hoping i could upload it as a string, trying to change the numpy array i have tried :

Comment: @kabanus arr = opencvImage
#ts = arr.tostring()
#tol = np.frombuffer(ts, dtype=int) and :                                       
import pickle
tss = pickle.dumps(arr)

tam = pickle.loads(tss)

Comment: Then ask "How do I insert a numpy array into a sql database" and give an example of what you actually want to do, and relevant code.

Comment: What you asked has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: [Numpy Array to SQL Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29897231/numpy-array-to-sql-table)

Comment: [edit] your question and put the code there, not in comments

Comment: @kabanus i was hoping to just take the values of the array which are printed out and set them to a string variable as to bypass the translation

Comment: [Working with NumPy Arrays and SQL](https://acviana.github.io/numpy-arrays-and-sql.html)

Comment: You obviously didn't read the link on the XY problem. Please do as I suggest or the question may be downvoted and/or closed.

Comment: @kabanus oh sorry never saw the link

Comment: That's OK.I suggest you check the links @Georgy offered, and if they don't help edit the question so we understand the actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Im not 100% sure what you are trying to accomplish but if you want the variable to be a string  just do:

```
a = str(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are trying to do is convert the numpy array to a string, this can be done using python's `str` function, like so:

```
b = np.array([1, 2, 3])
a = str(b)
```